# MT4 Keyboard shortcut for line drawing mode

Tags: drawing, shortcut, mode, mt4, trendline

Please help. I know how to use `CHARTEVENT_KEYDOWN` to get the key pressed and to use that to program an action for the key. However, I would like to program extra shortcuts to make use of existing MT4 interface functions and cannot find the appropriate programming language for it. If you want to create a trendline in MT4, you can click on the trendline button which puts MT4 in trendline drawing mode. I want to be able to press "l" and then have my code put the platform in trendline drawing mode. Please can you point me to the appropriate command to put MT4 into trendline drawing mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WinAPI `PostMessageW()` function to do the task.
You can use `#include <WinUser32.mqh>` to import the WinAPI function descriptions.

Then you can use these commands to perform the task you need.

(For trendline `#define MT4_WMCMD_TRENDLINE       33257`)

[Here you can find the commands](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/159017)

```
#define MT4_WMCMD_AUTOSCROLL      33017
#define MT4_WMCMD_BARS            33018
#define MT4_WMCMD_CANDLES         33019
                                        /* 33020       unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_GRID            33021
#define MT4_WMCMD_LINE            33022
#define MT4_WMCMD_SHIFT           33023
#define MT4_WMCMD_VOLUMES         33024
#define MT4_WMCMD_ZOOM_IN         33025
#define MT4_WMCMD_ZOOM_OUT        33026
                                        /* 33027-33047 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_EXPERT_INPUTS   33048 /* Open expert Inputs dialog */
                                        /* 33049       unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_REMOVE_EXPERT   33050 /* Remove expert advisor from chart */
                                        /* 33051-33053 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_SAVE_AS_PICTURE 33054
#define MT4_WMCMD_3_MONTHS        33057
#define MT4_WMCMD_ALL_HISTORY     33058
#define MT4_WMCMD_LAST_MONTH      33063
#define MT4_WMCMD_SAVE_Statement  33064 
                                        /* 33055-33133 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_D1       33134
                                        /* 33135       unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_H4       33136
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_M1       33137
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_M5       33138
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_M15      33139
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_M30      33140
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_W1       33141
                                        /* 33142-33156 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PROPERTIES      33157 /* Chart Properties (F8) */
                                        /* 33158-33176 apparently unused */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_SEPARATE 33177 /* Show/hide period separators */
                                        /* 33178-33196 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_MOVE_RIGHT      33197 /* Move right (right/down arrow) */
#define MT4_WMCMD_MOVE_LEFT       33198 /* Move left (left/up arrow) */
                                        /* 33199-33219 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_SAVE_TEMPLATE   33220 /* Save template... */
                                        /* 33221-33229 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33230           33230 /* Arrow Down */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33231           33231 /* Arrow Up */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33232           33232 /* icons-ticks */
#define MT4_WMCMD_MOUSE_CROSS     33233 /* crosshair */
#define MT4_WMCMD_MOUSE_CURSOR    33234 /* the cursor */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33235           33235 /* Box-cyclical Line */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33236           33236 /* equidistant channel */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33237           33237 /* Fibonacci lines */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33238           33238 /* Box-Fibonacci-arc */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33239           33239 /* Box-Fibonacci-fan */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33240           33240 /* Box Channels, Fibonacci */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33241           33241 /* Box-Gann-grid Hanna */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33242           33242 /* Box-Gann-line Hanna */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33243           33243 /* Box-Gann-fan Hanna */
#define MT4_WMCMD_HLINE           33244 /* horizontal line */
                                        /* 33245       unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33246           33246 /* Box Andrews pitchfork */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33247           33247 /* Box-shape-rectangle */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33248           33248 /* Box-channels-linear regression */
                                        /* 33249-33250 apparently unused */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33251           33251 /* Box-icons-stop */
                                        /* 33252       unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33253           33253 /* text */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33254           33254 /* Box-icons-bad */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33255           33255 /* Box-icons-well */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33256           33256 /* Box-Fibonacci-time-zone */
#define MT4_WMCMD_TRENDLINE       33257 /* trend line */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33258           33258 /* Box-Line-trend line for the corner */
#define MT4_WMCMD_33259           33259 /* Box-figure-triangle */
#define MT4_WMCMD_VLINE           33260 /* Vertical Line */
#define MT4_WMCMD_LABEL           33261 /* text label */
                                        /* 33262-33323 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_UPDATE_DATA     33324 /* This doesn't cause experts start() to run */
                                        /* 33325-33333 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_MN1      33334 /* timeframe MN */
                                        /* 33335-34299 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34300           34300 /* 34300-34699 custom indicators in alphabetical order */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34700           34700 /* Indicators-moving average of oscillator */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34701           34701 /* Indicators-accelerator oscillator */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34702           34702 /* Indicators-accumulation/distribution */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34703           34703 /* Indicators-alligator */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34704           34704 /* indicators-average directional movement index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34705           34705 /* indicators-average true range */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34706           34706 /* Indicators-awesome oscillator */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34707           34707 /* Indicators-bears power */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34708           34708 /* indicator-bollinger bands */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34709           34709 /* Indicators-bulls power */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34710           34710 /* Indicators-commodity channel index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34711           34711 /* Indicators-demarker */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34712           34712 /* Indicators-envelopes */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34713           34713 /* Indicators-force index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34714           34714 /* Indicators-fractals */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34715           34715 /* Indicators-gator oscillator */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34716           34716 /* Indicators-ichimoku kinko hyo */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34717           34717 /* Indicators-macd */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34718           34718 /* indicators-market facilitation index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34719           34719 /* Indicators-momentum */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34720           34720 /* indicators-money flow index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34721           34721 /* indicators-moving averages */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34722           34722 /* Indicators-on balance volume */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34723           34723 /* Indicators-parabolic sar */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34724           34724 /* indicators-relative strength index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34725           34725 /* indicators-relative vigor index */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34726           34726 /* Indicators-standard deviation */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34727           34727 /* Indicators-stochastic oscillator */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34728           34728 /* Indicators-volumes */
#define MT4_WMCMD_34729           34729 /* Indicators-william's percent range */
                                        /* 34730-34799 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_LOAD_TEMPLATE   34800 /* 34800-34899 load template in alphabetical order */
#define MT4_WMCMD_REMOVE_TEMPLATE 34900 /* 34900-34998 Remove Template in alph. order (conf. dialog) */
#define MT4_WMCMD_KILL_TEMPLATES  34999 /* remove *.tpl (confirmation dialog) */ 
                                        /* 35000-35399 unknown */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PERIOD_H1       35400 /* timeframe H1 */
#define MT4_WMCMD_OBJECTS_LIST    35402 /* open objects list window */
#define MT4_WMCMD_ORDER_BUYLIMIT  35454 /* order buy limit */
#define MT4_WMCMD_ORDER_BUYSTOP   35455 /* order buy stop */
#define MT4_WMCMD_ORDER_SELLLIMIT 35456 /* order sell limit */
#define MT4_WMCMD_ORDER_SELLSTOP  35457 /* order sell stop */
#define MT4_WMCMD_ORDER_MARKET    35458 /* new order (F9) */
#define MT4_WMCMD_35464           35464 /* right price tag */
#define MT4_WMCMD_35511           35511 /* Graphic template-download template */
                                        /* 35512-37011 unknown */
                                        /* 37012-40000 not inspected */
#define MT4_WMCMD_57602           57602 /* close the current chart */
#define MT4_WMCMD_57603           57603 /* Save as (ascii/csv) */
#define MT4_WMCMD_57604           57604 /* Save as (ascii/csv) - apparently same */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PRINT_DIALOG    57607 /* Open Print... Dialog */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PRINT_DIRECT    57608 /* Print immediately */
#define MT4_WMCMD_PRINT_PREVIEW   57609 /* Open Print Preview dialog */
                                        /* 57610-59675 unknown (re-checked up to 58011) */
                                        /* 59675-...   not inspected */
```